# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' 2

Tags: python

I need help with this error: "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' 2""

```
import operator
from numpy import *
def loadDataSet(filename):
    dataMat= []; labelMat= []
    fr = open(filename)
    for line in fr.readlines():
        lineArr = line.strip.split('\t')
        dataMat.append([float(lineArr[0]), float(lineArr[1])])
        labelMat.append(float(lineArr[2]))
    return dataMat, labelMat

def selectJrand(i, m):
    j=i
    while (j == i):
        j=int(random.uniform(0, m))
    return j

def clipAlpha(aj, H, L):
    if aj > H:
        aj=H
    if L > aj:
        aj = L
    return aj
```

**The bug as follows:**

```
dataArr, labelArr = svmMLiA.loadDataSet('testSet.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\python2.7.12\lib\svmMLiA.py", line 5, in loadDataSet
    lineArr = line.strip.split('\t')
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2):

Note `strip` is a class method, to call it, you have to use `strip()`. Just fix you code next way:

```
lineArr = line.strip().split('\t')
```

To get more information, read [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip).

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `strip` is a method that you need to call, just like `split`.

```
lineArr = line.strip().split('\t')
```

Comment: How to fixed it,I am confused.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it, 
lineArr = line.strip().split('\t')

Comment: lineArr = line.strip().split('\t')
should be write as follow:
line = line.strip()
lineArr = line.split('\t')